# Node.jsライブラリでキーボード入力ができない

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js

MacOSにて、ゲームパッドを利用して**文字入力がしたい**と思い、プログラムを作成していました。
使用している言語・環境はjavascript/node.js/Electron、ライブラリはrobot.jsです。

キーボードの入力のエミュレートは、制作初期は上手くいっていました。しかし、ある時からキーボード入力のメソッドを実行すると、文字が入力されずElectronが落ちるようになってしまいました。

エラーが表示されずに落ちるため、Electron抜きでテストしてみました。正しく動けば「a」が入力されるコードです。

```js
const robot=require('robotjs');
robot.keyTap('a');
```

結果、**文字は入力されず**、以下のような出力が出ました。

```bash
zsh: segmentation fault  node
```

このエラーについて調べたところ、segfault-handlerというライブラリで詳細ログが見れるということだったので、以下のように導入してみました。

```js
const SegfaultHandler = require('segfault-handler');
SegfaultHandler.registerHandler('crash.log');
const robot=require('robotjs');
robot.keyTap('a');
```

返ってきたログ出力は以下でした。
この出力の詳細は自分には読み解けませんでした。

```
PID 2643 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x0
0   segfault-handler.node               0x0000000106ea534c _ZL16segfault_handleriP9__siginfoPv + 288
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001b853d4c4 _sigtramp + 56
2   robotjs.node                        0x0000000106ed66d0 keyCodeForChar + 276
3   robotjs.node                        0x0000000106ed2b6c _Z6keyTapRKN3Nan20FunctionCallbackInfoIN2v85ValueEEE + 300
4   robotjs.node                        0x0000000106ed5818 _ZN3Nan3impL23FunctionCallbackWrapperERKN2v820FunctionCallbackInfoINS1_5ValueEEE + 208
5   node                                0x00000001027c4adc _ZN2v88internal25FunctionCallbackArguments4CallENS0_15CallHandlerInfoE + 540
6   node                                0x00000001027c4090 _ZN2v88internal12_GLOBAL__N_119HandleApiCallHelperILb0EEENS0_11MaybeHandleINS0_6ObjectEEEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_10HeapObjectEEESA_NS8_INS0_20FunctionTemplateInfoEEENS8_IS4_EENS0_16BuiltinArgumentsE + 504
7   node                                0x00000001027c3894 _ZN2v88internalL26Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCallENS0_16BuiltinArgumentsEPNS0_7IsolateE + 228
8   node                                0x0000000102f4bf8c Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit + 108
9   node                                0x0000000102ee6478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
10  node                                0x0000000102ee6478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
11  node                                0x0000000102ee6478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
12  node                                0x0000000102ee6478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
13  node                                0x0000000102ee6478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
14  node                                0x0000000102ee6478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
15  node                                0x0000000102ee6478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
16  node                                0x0000000102ee42ac Builtins_JSEntryTrampoline + 172
17  node                                0x0000000102ee3f44 Builtins_JSEntry + 164
18  node                                0x000000010288dcdc _ZN2v88internal12_GLOBAL__N_16InvokeEPNS0_7IsolateERKNS1_12InvokeParamsE + 2536
19  node                                0x000000010288d2dc _ZN2v88internal9Execution4CallEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_6ObjectEEES6_iPS6_ + 200
20  node                                0x000000010275d6fc _ZN2v88Function4CallENS_5LocalINS_7ContextEEENS1_INS_5ValueEEEiPS5_ + 448
21  node                                0x00000001025c54c8 _ZN4node19ExecuteBootstrapperEPNS_11EnvironmentEPKcPNSt3__16vectorIN2v85LocalINS6_6StringEEENS4_9allocatorIS9_EEEEPNS5_INS7_INS6_5ValueEEENSA_ISF_EEEE + 100
22  node                                0x00000001025c64a4 _ZN4nodeL14StartExecutionEPNS_11EnvironmentEPKc + 312
23  node                                0x00000001025c6350 _ZN4node14StartExecutionEPNS_11EnvironmentENSt3__18functionIFN2v810MaybeLocalINS4_5ValueEEERKNS_26StartExecutionCallbackInfoEEEE + 1044
24  node                                0x0000000102549970 _ZN4node15LoadEnvironmentEPNS_11EnvironmentENSt3__18functionIFN2v810MaybeLocalINS4_5ValueEEERKNS_26StartExecutionCallbackInfoEEEE + 136
25  node                                0x000000010262cb78 _ZN4node16NodeMainInstance3RunEPiPNS_11EnvironmentE + 72
26  node                                0x000000010262c888 _ZN4node16NodeMainInstance3RunEPKNS_16EnvSerializeInfoE + 120
27  node                                0x00000001025c847c _ZN4node5StartEiPPc + 180
28  dyld                                0x0000000107089088 start + 516
```

---

robot.jsと同じく、キーボードやマウスを操作できるnut.jsでも同様の処理をテストしてみました。こちらも以前は動いていました。

```js
const {keyboard}=require('@nut-tree/nut-js');
keyboard.type(45);
```

結果は同じでした。

```bash
zsh: segmentation fault  node
```

同じくsegfault-handlerを導入した際のコードとログ出力です。

```js
const SegfaultHandler = require('segfault-handler');
SegfaultHandler.registerHandler('crash.log');
const {keyboard}=require('@nut-tree/nut-js');
keyboard.type(45);
```

↓

```
PID 11392 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x0
0   segfault-handler.node               0x000000010719134c _ZL16segfault_handleriP9__siginfoPv + 288
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001922894c4 _sigtramp + 56
2   libnut.node                         0x00000001071f4054 keyCodeForChar + 276
3   libnut.node                         0x00000001071efa0c _Z7_keyTapRKN4Napi12CallbackInfoE + 188
4   libnut.node                         0x00000001071f3858 _ZN4Napi7details12WrapCallbackIZNS0_12CallbackDataIPFNS_6NumberERKNS_12CallbackInfoEES3_E7WrapperEP10napi_env__P20napi_callback_info__EUlvE_EEP12napi_value__T_ + 60
5   libnut.node                         0x00000001071f3800 _ZN4Napi7details12CallbackDataIPFNS_6NumberERKNS_12CallbackInfoEES2_E7WrapperEP10napi_env__P20napi_callback_info__ + 28
6   node                                0x00000001028a03b0 _ZN6v8impl12_GLOBAL__N_123FunctionCallbackWrapper6InvokeERKN2v820FunctionCallbackInfoINS2_5ValueEEE + 104
7   node                                0x0000000102aa8adc _ZN2v88internal25FunctionCallbackArguments4CallENS0_15CallHandlerInfoE + 540
8   node                                0x0000000102aa8090 _ZN2v88internal12_GLOBAL__N_119HandleApiCallHelperILb0EEENS0_11MaybeHandleINS0_6ObjectEEEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_10HeapObjectEEESA_NS8_INS0_20FunctionTemplateInfoEEENS8_IS4_EENS0_16BuiltinArgumentsE + 504
9   node                                0x0000000102aa7894 _ZN2v88internalL26Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCallENS0_16BuiltinArgumentsEPNS0_7IsolateE + 228
10  node                                0x000000010322ff8c Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit + 108
11  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
12  node                                0x00000001032742c0 Builtins_PromiseConstructor + 2208
13  node                                0x00000001031c76f0 Builtins_JSBuiltinsConstructStub + 368
14  node                                0x00000001032b87dc Builtins_ConstructHandler + 636
15  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
16  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
17  node                                0x00000001032742c0 Builtins_PromiseConstructor + 2208
18  node                                0x00000001031c76f0 Builtins_JSBuiltinsConstructStub + 368
19  node                                0x00000001032b87dc Builtins_ConstructHandler + 636
20  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
21  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
22  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
23  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
24  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
25  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
26  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
27  node                                0x00000001031ca478 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline + 248
28  node                                0x00000001031c82ac Builtins_JSEntryTrampoline + 172
29  node                                0x00000001031c7f44 Builtins_JSEntry + 164
30  node                                0x0000000102b71cdc _ZN2v88internal12_GLOBAL__N_16InvokeEPNS0_7IsolateERKNS1_12InvokeParamsE + 2536
31  node                                0x0000000102b712dc _ZN2v88internal9Execution4CallEPNS0_7IsolateENS0_6HandleINS0_6ObjectEEES6_iPS6_ + 200
```

---

別々のライブラリで似たエラーが起こっているので、アクセス権か何かが絡んでいるのかと予想していますが、これ以上具体的に掘り下げる手立てが思いつきません。
元々は動いていたコードだけに、ピンとくる原因がありません。何らかご教示いただければ幸いです。

MacOS Monterey 12.3
node v16.4.1
electron v13.1.5
robot.js 0.6.0
nut.js 2.0.1

#### 追記

Mac内で普段開発に使っているユーザーアカウントとは別のアカウントを作成し、上のコードを実行したところ、動きました。
これは普段のアカウント上で何らかのソフトウェアがキー入力を妨害していると見た方がよろしいのでしょうか？

#### 追記2（2022.6.26）

上のコードについて、

```
$ sudo node
```

コマンドで実行したところ、動きました。

『sudoでないとSegmentation Faultが起こる』というのは、コード的・環境的にどういう状況が考えられるのでしょうか？
最終的にElectronで使用したので、そのあたりを明らかにしたいです。

## 追記3（2022.7.4）

akira ejiri様の回答を受けて、システムコールトレースについて調べ、実際にやってみようとしました。

```
sudo dtruss -f sudo -u $(id -u -n) node ...
```

帰ってきた出力は以下でした。

```
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

dtrace: failed to execute sudo: Operation not permitted
```

この文から、System Integrity Protection (SIP) をオフにすれば動くのかと考え（ここからMacOSレベルの話になります）、以下のサイトを参考に、macOS復旧を起動してセキュリティ設定の変更を試みました。
https://www.too.com/support/faq/mac/maintenance/23554.html
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13252085413
https://ascii.jp/elem/000/004/048/4048177/2/

「ターミナル」で試した入力と出力

```bash
-bash-3.2# csrutil disable
csutil: The OS environment does not allow changing security configuration options.
Ensure that the system was booted into Recovery OS via the standard user action.
```

「起動セキュリティユーティリティ」を開いた時に出た警告

> **セキュリティ設定を変更できません。**
> セキュリティ設定を変更するには、Macの電源をオフにしてから、電源ボタンを押したままにしてmacOSの復旧を起動してください。

つまり、どちらも復旧メニューから実行しているにもかかわらず、『復旧からの起動でないと変更できない』と言われてしまうのです。

Comment: segmentation fault起きるのはほぼJavaScript側ではなくてElectronやC側の問題です。robot.jsのC実装のデバッグとOSX/XcodeのアップデートでAPIの挙動の変化を調べるとよさそうです。 https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/blob/c9cbd98ec47378dfae62871f0f2830782322b06d/src/keycode.c

Comment: そこまでするのは難儀ですね……Swiftで同様のコードは簡単な記述で動いたので、node.jsからSwiftを呼べれば良いのですが……

Answer (score 0):

> 『sudoでないとSegmentation Faultが起こる』というのは、コード的・環境的にどういう状況が考えられるのでしょうか？

root権限がないと失敗する処理(システムコール呼び出し等)があり、エラーチェックが疎かな場合、後続の処理で「Segmentation Fault」が発生しても不思議ではありません。

システムコールをトレースしてみると原因が分かるかもしれません。

```bash
sudo dtruss -f sudo -u $(id -u -n) node
```

rootユーザで実行するとエラーが再現されないようですので、rootで実行したときの結果と比較してみるのもよいと思います。

```bash
sudo dtruss -f node
```